# Getting the caller name from inside of the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-views

I'm invoking my view using

> @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.FileListBefore)

I would like to get the 'FileListBefore' name from the inside of the view.
How can I do that?

EDIT (more info):

'EditorFor(m => Model.FileListBefore)' uses my own sub-view. In that sub-view I want to retrieve the name of property which invoked this view.

Why? Because I'm calling

> @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.FileListBefore)
>
> @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.FileListAfter)

'FileListBefore' and 'FileListAfter' are the same type 'FileList' (my own class) and they call the same sub-view. I want to get the calling names ('FileListBefore' and 'FileListAfter) inside sub view because I want to identify them and add it do div 'id' value.

Comment: Here's a similar theme:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125809/aspnet-mvc-3-html-editorfor-a-subcollection-of-my-model-in-a-template

Comment: please explain a bit more. What do you mean by "get the  'FileListBefore' name from the inside of the view ". Where do you want to use that value?

Comment: I added some more info

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear to me. However, to simply see the property name which invoked the view, you can add `Debug.WriteLine("Inside <property name>");` inside every property so it gets printed in the Output Console of Visual Studio. If you want to print the name in a sub-view, you can add `<p>@ViewBag.PropertyName</p>` in the sub-view and add `ViewBag.PropertyName="<property name>";` inside every property.

By every property I imply all those properties that could call this View.