# TextBoxFor with List<object> always returns null to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a multi-line input or with a help of a script add several inputs to submit them as a List< object > to controller. If I use TextBoxFor I'm getting count=0 in controller for this List and null if I user EditorFor.
As I understand at the moment I'm just forming one Object but not a list of objects that's why it's null or count=0 ... but how to do it right?

**View:**

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        //other form-groups

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => @Model.MediaRSSURL)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => @Model.MediaRSSURL, "URL/URL", new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    }
</div>
```

**Class with List< object >:**

```
public class Media
{
    //other properties

    public List<URL> MediaRSSURL { get; set; }
}
```

**Class of the object:**

```
    public class URL
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string strURL { get; set; }
    public int MediaId { get; set; }
    public Media Media { get; set; }

}
```

**EditorTemplate:**

resides in *Shared/EditorTemplates/URL*

```
@model Domain.Entities.URL

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.strURL, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.MediaId)
</div>
```

**Controller POST method:**

```
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public RedirectToRouteResult AddMedia([FromBody] Media media)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _iMediaRepository.SaveMedia(media);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("GetAllMedia");
    }
```

**Controller GET method:**

```
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public ViewResult AddMedia()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

---

**Populate collection and pass model to View:**

```
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public ViewResult AddMedia()
    {
        var model = new Media();
        var newUrl = new URL();
        model.MediaRSSURL = new List<URL>();
        model.MediaRSSURL.Add(newUrl);

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Changed the Editor Template:**

```
    @model IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.URL>

<div class="form-group">

    @foreach (URL url in Model)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => url.strURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => url.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => url.MediaId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => url.Media)
    }

</div>
```

Comment: You cannot bind a textbox to a collection of complex objects. Your have an  `EditorTemplate` so use `@Html.EditorFor(m =>m.MediaRSSURL)` which will generate the html for each object in your collection based on the template.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've tried that and I get null if I use EdirorFor

Comment: Then that means you do not have any items in your collection! Show your GET method and how you populate the collection and pass it to the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've updated the post. My GET method is simple - I just return View(); Do I need to pass List<object> as model to View?

Comment: `return View();` does not pass a model to the view, so `MediaRSSURL` is `null`. Therefore there are no items to display

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I've changed the GET method, now I pass model to the view. As a model I pass a new instance of Media with a new List< URL > inside. As well I changed the Editor Template - now the model in the template is IEnumerable< URL > and I use foreach to iterate but still it returns null.  || See post update.

Comment: Do not use a `foreach`! All you need change is `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MediaRSSURL)` instead of `TextBoxFor(..)` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for more detail. If you have added some `URL` objects to your `MediaRSSURL` in the GET method then the html for each item will be correctly generated and bound

Comment: You have also mentioned some javascript to add objects but have not shown any code associated with that. Suggest you refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) if your wanting to dynamically add and delete collection items in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't have a script to add new inputs yet. I want to successfully pass list with one item at least. Then add "add more" functionality. If I don't use foreach I'm getting an Invalid Operation Exception in the view with explanation: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Domain.Entities.URL]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Domain.Entities.URL'.

Comment: Then clearly you have made other changes as well even though I told you not to!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Stephen thank you so much for your advises and links! There were some mistakes that prevented the code that you suggested from working. For example I misplaced the EditorTemplate location. Everything works now. I've updated the post with solution!

Answer (score 0):

---

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @stephen-muecke and his advises I managed to make it work!

**View Page:**

A nice [article](https://mhwelander.net/2014/03/26/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-not-occurring-when-posting-list-of-complex-types/) to understand how to deal with complex types. And also an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125809/aspnet-mvc-3-html-editorfor-a-subcollection-of-my-model-in-a-template/9143266#9143266) from the link above that helped me to figure one of my mistakes.
To dynamically add input I used technique from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) (Option2)

```
    @model Media

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {      
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MediaRSSURL)

            <div id="URLContainer">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MediaRSSURL)
            </div>
            <div id="URLfield" style="display: none">
                <!--You need to look in HTML how is your input formed and just copy it to make a fake input. Then replace the numbers in attributes by hashtag. For example name="MediaRSSURL[0].strURL" to name="MediaRSSURL[#].strURL"-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="MediaRSSURL_#__strURL" name="MediaRSSURL[#].strURL" type="text" value="" data-cip-id="MediaRSSURL_#__strURL">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Add URL" id="addURL" onclick="addURLs()"/>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    }
</div>

@section scripts
{

    <script>
        //On click you clone the fake input and replace all # signs to a number from counter and append new input to your container
        var counter = 1;
        $('#addURL')
            .click(function() {
                var clone = $('#URLfield').clone();
                // Update the indexer and Index value of the clone
                clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/#/g, counter));
                clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + counter + '"'));
                $('#URLContainer').append(clone.html());
                counter++;
            });

    </script>
}
```

**Class with List< object >:**

```
 public class Media
{
    // Other properties

    public List<URL> MediaRSSURL { get; set; }
}
```

**Class of the object:**

No changes

**Editor Template:**

Here is where I made a mistake and spent hours to understand it:
first the template was placed in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/URL/URL
And I needed it to have such location: Views/NameOfYourController/EditorTemplates/URL
Right after I changed the location of the Editor Template, attributes like name="MediaRSSURL[0].strURL" started generating in HTML letting me know that at last data from inputs would get to a list. Also I didn't have to specify the address to the template neither in EditorFor not in the model ( via [UIHint("URL")] ) - it works without those.

```
   @model Domain.Entities.URL

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.strURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
```

**Controller POST method:**

no major changes. No need of [FromBody] but it played no impact anyway at this time.

**Controller GET method:**

this is where I made second mistake - I first didn't pass model to View.
As well I initialized the **a)** model **b)** its List< object > **c)** and object

```
   [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
public ViewResult AddMedia()
{
    URL newUrl1 = new URL();
    var model = new Media();
    model.MediaRSSURL = new List<URL>();
    model.MediaRSSURL.Add(newUrl1);

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't works this way. because MediaRSSURL is return as List but you use it as textboxfor. if you can use it as listbox it will work or you should return it as string. so, this way

```
@model List<Domain.Entities.URL>
```

@foreach(item in model)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.strURL, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.MediaId)

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)